# gtkmm - path-variable missing

Tags: c++, environment-variables, gtkmm

I have recently installed gtkmm for developing apps and succeeded in installing the libs. At the least Eclipse does not complain about the headerfiles and the syntax in the code. It all looks good but when compiling I get the following:

```
Cannot run program "g++pkg-config": Launching failed

Error: Program "g++pkg-config" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:/Program/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program\Smart Projects\IsoBuster;c:\gtk3\bin;C:\Program\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\eclipse]
```

g++pkg-config seem to be missing. If this is the only problem, how do I include it?